# Create a Loadable Kernel Module (LKM) to block a range of IP addresses

Tags: c, linux, firewall, kernel-module, ipv4

I am trying to build a loadable kernel module (LKM) for Ubuntu Linux to block a range of IP addresses. My range of test addresses is 172.217.13.68/24. I have tried comparing the iphdr->saddr to the network and broadcast addresses of the range. The network and broadcast addresses are originally supplied as characters but then are type casted to unsigned int. When we use this method for the range, all web traffic packets are blocked instead of those just inside of the range. Any advice on how to perform the comparison?

**My code:**
Language C

```
static struct nf_hook_ops nfho; //struct holding set of hook function options

//function to be called by hook
unsigned int hook_func(
  void *priv,
  struct sk_buff *skb,
  const struct nf_hook_state *state

) {
        struct iphdr* iph;
    static unsigned char *blockIPLow = "\xAC\xD9\x00\x00";
    static unsigned char *blockIPHigh = "\xAC\xD9\x00\xFF";

    if(skb){
            iph = ip_hdr(skb);

    if(iph && (iph->saddr>= *(unsigned int*)blockIPLow) && (iph->saddr<= *(unsigned int*)blockIPHigh))
        {
    printk(KERN_INFO "dropRange.c -- hook_func() dropped packets in range\n");
        return NF_DROP;
        }
    }

  /////////////////////  
  // ACCEPT ALL OTHER PACKETS
  /////////////////////
  return NF_ACCEPT;
}
```

**Update:** This exact code worked with a small range of IPs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most systems are little-endian. So your cast from string to int is reversing the bytes. So you are in fact checking for addresses bigger than 0.0.227.172 and smaller than 255.0.227.172, which of course covers most addresses.

If you really insist on using this unsafe cast, reverse the string order, but of course then it would fail on a big- endian system.

Comment: I previously put it in little endian order and it did not work for blocking a single IP's. When I try blocking a single IP, the code works. I could ping all addresses around it except for that address. However, my range comparison does not work